# ManagementObjectSearcher Get() method: "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program."

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, wmi

- I read all the related answers here neither helps.
- Also please note: If I run the program in the VS 2012 debugger it works like a charm.
  However if I run without debugging (ctrl F5) or run the .exe outside of the VS 2012 ID it throws the exception.
- I turened off the Firewall
- I run the exe as Admin
- I restarted WMI service.

Same..

Here is the code. The exception is thrown by the .Get() method call

NOTE: THe debug screen is *not* from running debug mode, it is from running the executable and after crash attaching the debugger.

http://screencast.com/t/nfvrfz2Hq6Q

Again, if I run the program in debug more it runs like the charm.

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice");

        var objCollection = objSearcher.Get();

        foreach (var obj in objCollection)
        {
            foreach (var property in obj.Properties)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", property.Name, property.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for feedback: Can anyone reproduce this? Thx

Comment: OOM is the expected outcome for this code if the *real* code repeatedly runs this query.  It takes a while.  Otherwise the typical outcome of using classes that implement IDisposable, not using the Dispose() method and not having the garbage collector run often enough to clean up after you.  These are however very pertinent details that you left out of your question so it is not an explanation.

Comment: Hi Hans, thx for the comment. Code run once. What is a real scary here that in VS IDE debug mode it runs fine and finds 2 devices, but running the execurably (or running in IDE with ctrl+f5) it instantly throws an out of memory. :-( I am hopeless.

Comment: There's no simple explanation for that.  Audio drivers are troublesome in general.  Play with [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to experiment.  Be sure to query only the properties you actually need to minimize the lossage.

Answer (score 0):

yes I can reproduce it, your problem should be permissions, run the program as administrator, in my case it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "options" are set to default impersonation.
**Try the following**

```
internal static class WmiQuery
{
    public static ManagementScope getWmiConnection(string ipAddress, string username = "", string password = "", string domain = "")
    {
        //New ConnectionOptions.
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        bool isLocalhost = (ipAddress.ToLower() == "localhost" || ipAddress == "127.0.0.1");
        //ConnectionOptions'Properties invullen.
        options.Impersonation = isLocalhost ? ImpersonationLevel.Default : ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        options.Username = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, username);
        options.Password = password;

        ManagementScope scope = isLocalhost
            ? new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ipAddress + "\\root\\cimv2")
            : new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ipAddress + "\\root\\cimv2", options);

        return scope;
    }

    public static ManagementObjectCollection SearcherGet(this ManagementScope scope, string query)
    {
        //Query system for Operating System information
        if (!scope.IsConnected) scope.Connect();
        var queryResult = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery(query)).Get();
        return queryResult;

    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        var wmiConn = WmiQuery.getWmiConnection("localhost");
        ManagementObjectCollection results = wmiConn.SearcherGet("SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice");

        foreach (var soundDevice in results)
            foreach (var sdProperty in soundDevice.Properties)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", sdProperty.Name, sdProperty.Value);
    }
}
```

Now simply call:

```
WmiQuery.DoWork();
```